# For loop to increment

Tags: for-loop, awk

How can I add the loop for "commandx"?

**tst.awk**

```
BEGIN { FS="," }
{
    printf "echo %s %s", $1, $2
    for (i=3; i<=NF;i=i+1) {
        printf " commandx %s", $i
        }
    print "command"
}
```

**test.txt**

```
"a1","b1","c1"
"a2","b2","c2","d2"
"a3","b3","c3","d3","e3"
```

**Output:**

```
echo "a1" "b1" commandx "c1" command
echo "a2" "b2" commandx "c2" commandx "d2" command
echo "a3" "b3" commandx "c3" commandx "d3" commandx "e3" command
```

**Expected Output:**

```
echo "a1" "b1" command1 "c1" command
echo "a2" "b2" command1 "c2" command2 "d2" command
echo "a3" "b3" command1 "c3" command2 "d3" command3 "e3" command
```

Answer (score 2):

use the [`sprintf()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function and loop on `i`

```
BEGIN { FS="," }
{
    output = sprintf("echo %s %s", $1, $2)
    for (i=3; i<=NF;i=i+1) {
        output = output sprintf(" command%n %s",i-2, $i)
        }
    output = output "command"
    print output
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the `x` in `commandx` is supposed to be populated with ever increasing numbers (starting with `1` and counting up to `NF-2`):

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS="," }
{
    printf "echo %s %s", $1, $2
    for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) {
        printf " command%s %s", (i-2), $i
        }
    print " command"
}' test.txt
```

This generates:

```
echo "a1" "b1" command1 "c1" command
echo "a2" "b2" command1 "c2" command2 "d2" command
echo "a3" "b3" command1 "c3" command2 "d3" command3 "e3" command
```

Answer (score -1):

try changing

printf " commandx %s", $i

to

printf(" command%d %s", i-2, i)

?